# How to correctly load js file into angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to add external js file to angular project.

angular.json:

```
"scripts": [
          "src/ebapi-modules.js"
        ]
```

After that I'm able to use functions from this module in html, but I want also to use it in my components and services.

So reading lots of answers I created typings.d.ts in src.
and declare variable:

```
declare var EB: any;
```

I'm not sure what name of variable I should use here? The EB is a name of a function, but not sure if this is correct.

I also tried to import it like that in my component:

```
import * as EB from '../../ebapi-modules';
```

Then I tried to use it like that:

```
fnScanEnable() {
   EB.Barcode.enable({ allDecoders: true }, this.fnBarcodeScanned);
   this.scanData = "Scanner enabled";
}
```

The module ebapi-modules.js is not in npm.

How do I correctly load js file to an Angular 7 app?

Comment: did you solve the problem? i am currently trying to add the ebapi-modules.js but cannot find them..